# Fluent Builder/DSL in Java by Example

Tags: java, tree, dsl, fluent, api-design

I have a Java app where I need to represent a simple arithmetic expression as a tree. The operations I will be supporting include unary (!, unary negation, etc.), binary (+, -, *, /) and even tertiary (custom functions) operations. As such I've selected the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` as the structure to represents my math tree, because these trees can have 0+ child nodes.

For instance, the expression: `3 + 4 * someFunc(2, 6, 9)` would be represented as the following tree:

```
        *
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    +     someFunc
   / \       /|\
  /   \     / | \
 3     4    2 6  9
```

This is because of operator precedence (multiplication trumps addition and the `someFunc` method must resolve to a value before it can be an argument to the root multiplication).

Anyways, I need a way to programmatically-build up these trees easily, and would like to use a Java DSL (`Fluent Builder` pattern) to accomplish this.

For the nodes:

```
public abstract class MathNode {

}

public abstract class OperatorNode extends MathNode {

}

public class Addition extends OperatorNode {
    // Same for Multiplication, SomeFunc, and every other supported operator.
}

public class Number extends MathNode {
    // 3, 4, 2, 6, 9, etc.
}
```

Then, I might be able to have a fluent builder/DSL like so:

```
// Uses DefaultMutableTreeNode for internal structure.
MathTreeBuilder treeBuilder = new MathTreeBuilder();

treeBuilder.multiply()
    .add(3,4)
    .someFunc(2,6,9);

MathTree tree = treeBuilder.build();
```

However I'm having a tough time seeing the "forest" through the "trees" here. Do I need a builder at all, or can I just accomplish the same by having the DSL be apart of `MathTree` itself? What would the DSL look like - am I on track or have I misunderstood the use of the fluent builder pattern? And, most importantly, in each of the different DSL methods (`add()`, `multiply()`, `someFunc()`, etc.), how do I actually go about modifying the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to accurately represent the tree?

Comment: And what is `DefaultMutableTreeNode`? Also, do you need to build the parser by yourself or can you use an external one (I am thinking about parboiled here)?

Comment: I really don't see a fluent API as being the answer here. It's still going to be hard to read and use. If you don't need to write it yourself (homework), then I agree with @fge that using an existing solution is highly preferable.

Comment: Thanks @fge (+1) - [`DefaultMutableTreeNode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) is a tree that ships with the JDK that I *believe* is the best way to actually represent my tree structure. It allows each node to have 0+ child nodes, which is what I want. If you disagree and think another structure is more appropriate, then by all means, please let me know if you have any suggestions!

Comment: Thanks @EricStein (+1) - this is definitely not homework. My tree in real life is much more complicated than a simple artithmetic tree. I'm just looking for the general approach here. **Most importantly,** if you think the fluent API is not going to help out here, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: And @fge, not sure what you mean by "parser". Here, every time someone calls a fluent API method, it should modify the `DefaultMutableTreeNode` under the hood.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were trying to parse a tree...

Comment: @TotesMcGotes I might consider hand-rolling a node, just so you don't have the baggage associated with a class intended for use in Swing. If you really insist on fluency, ask a coworker to throw together five significantly different expressions, and then try to come up with a fluent API that handles all of them. I think it will be very challenging. For instance, in your example, multiply() is no-arg and acts as a prefix method to its two subexpressions, but those both take arguments which are the concrete values. What happens when instead of somefunc(2, 6, 9) you have somefunc(2, 10 - 4, 9)?

Comment: @TotesMcGotes I'm working on it. :-)

Comment: Thanks @EricStein - and again (+2) for all the help/advice so far!

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go about this the way an XML builder would work:

- yes, use fluent API;
- no need to strictly follow the Builder pattern: you don't have to finish building with an "export" into an immutable object;
- internally to your builder, maintain the tree and your *current position* in it: the node which currently receives children;
- have an explicit `end()` method which makes the current node's parent the new current node.

Then you can build your `3 + 4 * someFunc(2, 6, 9)` as follows:

```
new MathBuilder()
.add()
  .const(3)
  .multiply()
     .const(4)
     .someFunc()
        .const(2)
        .const(6)
        .const(9)
     .end()
 .get();
```

All the trailing `end()` calls may be omitted. I have left one in to serve as an example.

Comment: In this proposal, I assume all methods return a MathBuilder instance?

Comment: Sorry, I meant do all methods return *the same* MathBuilder instance? And how do you prevent invalid calls, like new MathBuilder().const(5).const(6).get()?

Comment: Yes, the same instance is returned.

Comment: So the result of new MathBuilder().const(5).const(6).get() is 5 or 6? It *may* also be an issue that you're allowing too much flexibility - if operations must be unary/binary/trinary, that isn't being enforced here.

Comment: The result is an exception the second time you call `const` because the current node (a generic root) accepts only one child. You can easily enforce arity with this approach.

Comment: To be clear, I like it as a fluent solution, I'm just unconvinced that fluent is the way to go here. <shrug/> At the end of the day, the OP will come up with something.

Comment: The key advantage to fluent APi is that it allows you to split the building in several steps. You can use loops to build up certain parts etc. When you rely on having everything available to the constructor, you have constrained yourself to building up an expression in a single go, almost like a huge Java literal.

Comment: Hm. Looking at it again, the constructor-based approach seems like it would work best when the expression is coming in postfix. That way it can be built incrementally. Otherwise, yes, you need the whole expression available. It's unclear what the OP's data looks like, so it's hard to tell if that's relevant.

Comment: You might also want to consider returning different object types besides just MathBuilder. That would let you enforce fixed arity, at least, without resorting to throwing a runtime exception (yuck!). Also, with fixed arity, you don't really need the end() calls .. they only matter for variable arity.

Comment: If you use loops to build the expression, then of course runtime exceptions are the only option. Anyway, I'm not a huge fan of overengineering just to achieve the best static typing you can possibly get. Static typing buys you very little in terms of production-time reliability because the errors it catches are of the most obvious kind.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to try a non-fluent solution, this might work:

```
interface Expression {
    public Node asTree();
}

public final class Value implements Expression {
    public Value(final int value) { .. }
    public Node asTree();
}

public final class Negate implements Expression {
    public Negate(final Expression e) { .. }
    public Node asTree();
}

public final class Multiply implements Expression {
    public Multiply(final Expression e1, final Expression e2) { .. }
    public Node asTree();
}
```

It doesn't read nearly as pretty as the fluent option, but if you're building piece-by-piece it should be easier to work with. I think it's also easy to unit test.

Comment: Yeah, that was originally a class. The perils of coding in a textfield. :-) I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a builder pattern would be relevant in this case. You're building a tree, and builders are not very suitable for building trees.
I would use instead some static factory methods instead:

```
Math.multiply(
   Math.add(3, 4),
   Math.someFunc(2, 6, 9)
 );
```

That would be equivalent to:

```
new Multiply(new Add(3, 4), new SomeFunc(2, 6, 9));
```

PS: don't use `DefaultMutableTreeNode`: it is a Swing framework class, and you don't want to depend on a UI framework for making a mathematic expression framework. And worst, it is mutable. Create your own structure.

Comment: Great until you have a requirement to incrementally build the expression, for example by reading some input source.

Comment: BTW what *exactly* is wrong with depending on a standard JDK class, having no dependencies on GUI classes, which just happens to reside in the `javax.swing` hierarchy? Is it the offending word `swing` which appears in the import section of the file?

Comment: It is conceptually wrong to depend on javax.swing because it is a GUI package. A simple example: it is not available on Android. But even if  it were available on all Java implementations, it would still be wrong.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. BTW I was going to say that right away, but I bit my tongue when I saw it was really a neutral, general-purpose class. It may be a bit awkward, but it is not wrong, not for any real-life reason.

Comment: To complete: I'm not sure this class would be available on J2EE servers, because there is no reason to be the case. You can see Swing as a UI framework shipped by default with JavaSE, but it's not part of the language core as the String or ArrayList classes would be.

Comment: Of course it is available on JEE because JEE is just an addition to JavaSE. Whenever you target standard Java (as opposed to Android, which isn't even Java according to strict Oracle policy), you have Swing bundled in. Swing can even be used in headless mode, which is actually useful in production JEE systems, for example to build Jasper reports.